# How to revert an old git merge on master but still preserve future commits / merges

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request, git-revert

If a PR is merged on to master (say `PR b`) and after which a couple of more PRs (say `PR c`, `PR d`, `PR e`) have been merged that made changes to same / other random files in the repo; how can we revert `PR b` but still keep the changes from the other PRs?

```
Day 1      master
Day 2      prevMaster->b
Day 3      prevMaster->b->c
Day 4      prevMaster->b->c->d
Day 5      prevMaster->b->c->d->e
```

How to do this?:

```
Day 6      prevMaster->c->d->e
```

Comment: `git rebase -p --onto prevMaster b`?

Comment: `git revert b`?